# How do I get estimated battery life on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, power-management

Back in the good ol' Windows Mobile day (CE based) one good get a rough estimate of battery life using the CE CoreDll.dll. Well sometimes at least depending on your hardware. This was exposed via [GetSystemPowerStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453172.aspx).

WP7 being SilverLight based I'm assuming these sorts of Interop approaches will no longer work. Is there an API that exposes power status info? I've done a quick search and browse but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no API method that will return the battery life.